# PyPDF2 - Accessing visitor function parameters

Tags: pypdf

Using PyPDF2, I am trying to return text from a PDF, filtered by the font weight & style. However, I am so far unable to figure out how to access the "fontDict" object in the visitor function below.

type(fontDict) returns a <class 'PyPDF2.generic._data_structures.DictionaryObject'>, but I cannot figure out which method returns the keyword / values?

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfReader


reader = PdfReader("E:\\Programming\\nlp\\documents_to_search\\GeoBase_NHNC1_Data_Model_UML_EN.pdf")
page = reader.pages[0]

def visitor_body(text, cm, tm, fontDict, fontSize):
    print(fontDict['/BaseFont'])
        
        
page.extract_text(visitor_text=visitor_body)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [source code for the DictionaryObject class](https://pypdf2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/PyPDF2/generic/_data_structures.html) indicates that it inherits from `PdfObject` and `dict`, so you should be able to access the keys and values as you would for any `dict` instance:

```
def visitor_body(text, cm, tm, fontDict, fontSize):
    keys = fontDict.keys()
    values = fontDict.values()
```

Comment: You're correct, the problem I had is that the first return from each text object on the page was None, causing me to receive a NoneType error each time I tried to access the key / value pairs.